# Moving the title tag to the top of the head tag in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, seo

Joomla! generates the meta tags before the title tag, For SEO Purposes, I would like to change it the other way, first title, and then meta tags, CSS, JS and other stuff.

I know I can do it by changing the order in the *head.php* file, but hacking the core files is very bad because when I'll want to update the system version, what I did will be removed.

Is there any other way to do that? maybe from the template or even by an extension?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a plugin to re-order this section via a regex search-and-replace before the page is displayed on the screen.

Looking at head.php, the simplest solution I can think of is that I see that it sniffs to see if a meta tag exists before outputting it to the page (sadly, it does not do this with the title tag).

In your template, you could always save the meta data values in parameters, then unset it each one with code along the lines of

```
JFactory::getDocument()->setGenerator('');
```

You could display the head as normal below this (which should now have the title at the top due to having no meta data to display)...

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

... before hardcoding your metadata using the saved parameters beneath this.

The above all said, I would really question your SEO.  I cannot think of a single reason why Google should penalise a site for having a title tag below the metadata. If it was a well known SEO no-no, then Joomla would likely have updated it - it would be a very small bug to fix.  It sounds like SEO hearsay rather than anything real, and so fixing it would be bulking up your codebase for no good reason.